# Flutter app enters build method but no widget is being built on the screen

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a bottom navigation bar in my app with 2 or 3 pages on condition. When I pick all the other pages the screens are built and the screen has content. When I try to enter the session screen, a white screen is displayed with no content except the bottom navigation bar and the app bar, print messages are being displayed and the debugger does enter the build method which is even more weird. I have tried changing the widget being built, delegating to a separate widget all together from the screen, running `flutter clean`, restarting the emulator (cold boot as well). It is very bizarre. I can't see anything that is wrong or different from the other screens.

tabs_screen.dart

```
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_uni_access/models/uni_user.dart';
import 'package:flutter_uni_access/screens/new_session_screen.dart';
import 'package:flutter_uni_access/screens/user_classes_screen.dart';
import 'package:flutter_uni_access/screens/user_info_screen.dart';

class TabsScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  late final UniUser user;

  TabsScreen(this.user);

  @override
  State<TabsScreen> createState() => _TabsScreenState();
}

class _TabsScreenState extends State<TabsScreen> {
  late List<Map<String, Object>> _pages;
  int _selectedIndex = 0;

  @override
  void initState() {
    if (!widget.user.isTeacher!) {
      _pages = [
        {'page': UsertInfoScreen(widget.user), 'title': 'Info'},
        {'page': UserClassesScreen(widget.user), 'title': 'Classes'}
      ];
    } else {
      _pages = [
        {'page': UsertInfoScreen(widget.user), 'title': 'Info'},
        {'page': UserClassesScreen(widget.user), 'title': 'Classes'},
        {'page': NewSessionScreen(widget.user), 'title': 'Session'}
      ];
    }
    super.initState();
  }

  void _onTabTapped(int index) {
    setState(() {
      _selectedIndex = index;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(_pages[_selectedIndex]['title'] as String),
        actions: [
          IconButton(
              onPressed: () => FirebaseAuth.instance.signOut(),
              icon: const Icon(Icons.logout))
        ],
      ),
      body: _pages[_selectedIndex]['page'] as Widget,
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
        unselectedItemColor: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.secondary,
        selectedItemColor: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.primary,
        type: BottomNavigationBarType.shifting,
        items: widget.user.isTeacher!
            ? const [
                BottomNavigationBarItem(
                    icon: Icon(Icons.person), label: 'Info'),
                BottomNavigationBarItem(
                    icon: Icon(Icons.school), label: 'Classes'),
                BottomNavigationBarItem(
                    icon: Icon(Icons.class_), label: 'Session')
              ]
            : const [
                BottomNavigationBarItem(
                    icon: Icon(Icons.person), label: 'Info'),
                BottomNavigationBarItem(
                    icon: Icon(Icons.school), label: 'Classes')
              ],
        currentIndex: _selectedIndex,
        onTap: _onTabTapped,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

new_session_screen.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:nfc_manager/nfc_manager.dart';
import 'package:flutter_uni_access/models/uni_user.dart';

class NewSessionScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  final UniUser user;

  NewSessionScreen(this.user);

  @override
  State<NewSessionScreen> createState() => _NewSessionScreenState();
}

class _NewSessionScreenState extends State<NewSessionScreen> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const Center(
      child: Text('TEST'),
    );
  }
}
```

**EDIT**
I added a text button widget and it built it... I don't know why it wouldn't build the text widget but it built the text button. I will continue, though if someone has the answer to this I would be happy to know/learn.

**2nd EDIT**
I discovered the problem. It was my own stupidity. I had given white to all text colors because of my usual background colors. So it's only logical that I couldn't spot the white text in the white background.

Comment: What if you put `NewSessionScreen` as the first in _pages or put another screen like a `UserClassesScreen` in the third spot?

Comment: @IvoBeckers If I put `NewSessionScreen` in the first position or in a different position it behaves as before, white screen and the other screen behaves normally. If I put another screen in the third spot the same. It's like it's cursed :P